# How to convert nvarchar type to only time type format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, error-handling, date-format

I have a column of type `nvarchar` i.e `170948` I want to store it in time type column

For that I had written

```
select @CurrentTimeValue=Convert(time, items, 108) from T
```

but it is throwing error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please suggest the correct format

Comment: Check [the official SQL Server Books Online documentation on `CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - it lists **ALL** the valid, supported date and time formats for `CONVERT` - pick the one that works for you

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the supported `CONVERT` styles match your input, you'll have to tweak your input manually - something like this:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(10) = '170948'

DECLARE @modified VARCHAR(10)

SET @modified = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@input, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@input, 2)

SELECT CAST(@modified AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
select cast(stuff(stuff('170948', 5,0,':'), 3,0,':') as time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(stuff(stuff('170948', 3,0,':'), 6,0,':') as time)
```